# Formula for Points of a Projection

Tags: geometry

Given a projection from the point $(-1,1)$ that maps $y = 2x$ onto $ y = 2x - 3$. How do I find a formula for where the points of $y = 2x$ map on $ y = 2x - 3$? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three points are collinear if their homogeneous coordinates (i.e. $1$ appended as last coordinate) results in a zero determinant. So you want

$$0=\begin{vmatrix}-1&x&x'\\1&y&y'\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}-1&x&x'\\1&2x&2x'+3\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}
=3x'+3$$

As you can see, the solution is $x'=-1$ no matter what value you choose for $x$. Which makes a lot of sense, since the center of projection $(-1,1)$ lies on the line $y=2x+3$ so a projection through that point onto that line will project everything to that single point.